# VacationSettings.endTime in Gmail API is converting to the wrong date -- is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to update my Gmail vacation responder by using [`Gmail.users.settings.updateVacation`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updateVacation). I am passing a [`VacationSettings`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/VacationSettings) like so:

```
{
    "restrictToContacts": false,
    "responseBodyHtml": "test",
    "responseSubject": "Out Of Office",
    "enableAutoReply": true,
    "restrictToDomain": false,
    "startTime": 1638933300000,
    "endTime": 1638936900000
}
```

`startTime` and `endTime` are `epoch ms` and translate to:

```
| key       | value         | date                     |
|-----------|---------------|--------------------------|
| startTime | 1638933300000 | 2021-12-07 @ 10:15:00 PM |
| endTime   | 1638936900000 | 2021-12-07 @ 11:15:00 PM |
```

But, in Gmail, it's setting the end date to `2021-12-06`:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25922#:%7E:text=When%20your%20vacation%20reply%20is%20sent), or what you see on the Gmail browser UI, you **can** schedule the vacation responder to turn on or off at the hour/minute/second. The Gmail browser UI may show the wrong date, but it **will** turn on and off as expected.

So, for example, setting `endTime` to be a few minutes from now, will turn the vacation responder off at that time, even though the Gmail browser UI doesn't indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail Vacation responder works on a daily basis rather than hourly, so only the date is taken from the provided timestamp.

The end day you provide is taken as the first day that you're back, so for example an end date of December 20th 2021 would mean the vacation responder works up to and including the 19th rather than the end of the 20th.

Comment: Humm. The key names are `startTime` and `endTime`. Having `Time` in their made me think it works to the time level. Let me test something.

Comment: Okay, so, this is interesting. I set a OOO to start now and end 5 minutes from now. It showed the wrong date in the Gmail UI **but** it did automatically turn my OOO off after 5 minutes. So the code works as expected -- the UI just doesn't show the right thing.